# Power source of separately or self excited AC generator

Tags: generator

Please can somebody explain me where the power needed to excite non permanent magnet generator comes from,as in the beginning,generator itself hasn't produced any electrical power to generate magnetism (further magnetism is necessary to produce electricity).

Comment: The grid? Battery? Diesel generator?

Comment: Separately answer me for each of those..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'm assuming basic generator parts knowlegde here, please comment if this isn't the case.*

There basically are three methods to get forward **synchronous** generators to put some current in the [exciter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excitation_(magnetic)) in order to power up.

1. The most common way is to rely on [remnant magnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remanence). Since generators are massive lumps of metal there is always some magnetism left. Without load, this remnant magnetism is enough to get anywhere from 10 to 200 volts. Depending on the generator itself. This is enough to power up the voltage regulator.
   Often a small permanent magnet is wounding inside one of the coils to help.
2. But sometimes this is not enough and external power is required. Which can be as small as a 9v battery, or the 12/24 Volt start battery through a current limiting resistor*. This is called field flashing.
3. A more reliable way is to attach a PMG ([permanent magnet generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_magnet_synchronous_generator)). Which powers the voltage regulator directly providing enough energy as long as the speed is sufficient. These are often high pole count units, giving a higher frequency.

---

But there is also reverse excitation. This is a kind of counterintuitive method, a bit rare. But nonetheless found on many ships due to some benefits.
**All** power of the auxiliary smaller windings is put into the excitation giving you 100% excitation.
The voltage regulator has then to divert this current to **reduce** the voltage. 
Or work against it with an opposite exciter. Again, depending on the exact type.
The generator will always make enough voltage to start the regulator electronics, even if broken, so sometimes a bit too much...

---

Your common small portable backup generator will most like use the most economical method 1. But I'm not 100% sure since I never work with those.

**And contactor with diodes due to back-emf of the exciter.*

Comment: Which kind of generators need permanent DC supply?

Comment: @ShashankPandey large static exciter generators (with slip rings for the exciter). These are often huge machines as backup generator for a large facility or power plant.

Comment: So,which one is used in our domestic generators?

Comment: and one more thing,generators relying upon remnant magnetism too need an exciter circuit from stator winding terminals?